# Calculate beta coefficient from t stat

Tags: regression, linear

I have T value and p value from summary statistics of a large (~300) eQTL dataset. I need beta and SE estimates for some downstream analysis. Can I approximate these values?

Comment: You need to describe your question in more detail.

Comment: If you mean by "T" the Student $t$ statistics for regression coefficients, then apart from the sign of the coefficient (which is the sign of $t$) you have *absolutely no* information about the actual values of those coefficients or their SEs: all you know is their ratios (which is what $t$ is).

Comment: If I have T stat, P value from T stat and N for any dataset, using these values can I approximate beta estimate and Std. Error?

Comment: Not a chance, I'm afraid.  You could figure out $N$ from $t$ and the p-value alone, so that gives you no additional information.